# CSV is not creating format problems with integer value when generated through SSIS package

Tags: excel, ssis, csv

I am trying to generate a CSV file from DB Query as source one of my column is having datatype  nvarchar(50) with values as "01050007029604301001"
After the export when the csv file is viewed using Excel the value appears as
"1.0500E18" .
How can i stop this .
Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's Excel treating it as a number - it *could* be one after all.  One workaround is to prefix affected fields with = in your csv file:

```
"01","02","wibble"
```

becomes

```
="01",="02","wibble"
```

and so on.  This will prevent the loss of leading zeros and display the full value with out conversion to scientific notation.

Comment: it worked :) just minor addition the actual expression can be used
"=" + "\"" + columnName + "\""